# Exclude model properties when saving with Ember-Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a model that has an `image` property. When saving images I would like to not Post that property to the endpoint. I was thinking perhaps I could `.set` the changes on everything beside the `image` property then save. But save still posts everything.

Also, my Adapter supports PATCH so I can successfully save portions of the model.

My model

```
App.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  description: attr(),
  image: attr(),
  authors: hasMany('author'),
  imageURL: function() {
    return document.location.origin + '/media/' + this.get('image');
  }.property('image'),
  created: attr('date')
});
```

My Controller

```
App.PhotoController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      this.get('model').save().then(function(success) {
        self.transitionToRoute('photos').then(function() {
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `serializeAttribute` function on the `Serializer`:

```
App.PhotoSerializer = DS.DjangoRESTSerializer.extend({
    serializeAttribute: function(record, json, key, attribute) {
        if (attribute.name !== 'image') {
            this._super(record, json, key, attribute);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce and results. I logged attribute without any results.

Comment: That should have worked ;)  I'll edit my answer with another suggestion

Comment: PhotoSerializer returns an error `No model was found for '0'`. This should be named after the model, correct?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through the `serialize` function?

Comment: I have, the application halts as soon as it reaches the class. When I change the name to Photos instead of Photo it works but doesn't output anything.

Comment: I don't understand "halts as soon as it reaches the class".  Can you be more specific?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46541/discussion-between-steve-h-and-zach-shallbetter)

Comment: I added the fix from our discussion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 15):

I think since this [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2106/commits) on Ember there is a better way to handle the exclusion of an attribute.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    image: {serialize: false}
  }
});
```

If you have more than one attribute to exclude the above code looks cleaner. Also have a look on the documentation of [DS.JSONSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html#property_attrs)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the PR has been merged over a year ago.

Comment: + check the article about [Customizing Serializers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/customizing-serializers/)